# how to check in angularJS's run function that a text file exists?

Tags: angularjs, html, file

i have a text file

> firstTime.txt

in root directory of my project.  Now in AngualrJS's run function i want to check that is this file available or not ?? if available then delete.

**is this possible to check that a file is exists or not and delete it in angularJS' run function?**

Comment: you want to delete file from javascript? You must not.

Comment: On server or client side?